# How to change button Color to red when i have wrong result with angular js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

i want to change A "Run button" to red when i don't have the expected results and to green when i have the right one .
So How could i do that with angularjs??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTxcZ.png)

Comment: Try use `ng-class` or `ng-style` conditionally

Comment: Docs for `ng-style` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-class and your can change the class on the basis of if condition. Let me try to create JsFiddle link for you.

Comment: hey , i could not found any code in this link . could you write it again please ?

Comment: Fiddle link is lost, Here is the simple example for you.
<div ng-class="{1:'test_yes', 0:'test_no'}[status]"></div>